# Firebase authentication network error on Android using Ionic app

Tags: android, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have Ionic2 app running well on windows chrome. I am using Firebase.
When running on Android emulator I am getting a network error:

```
A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
```

I tried few suggestions with no success:

- I changed the button from submit type to button type
- I checked the whitelist
- I removed the usage of a form.

Nothing worked.

Is there anything I should configure in Firebase before running the web app on Android?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it finally, The answer is the whitelist. I had to run the following commands:
**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist**
and
**cordova prepare**

I did t once before but I probably missed something so I did it again. I don't really understand the meaning of it so I cannot explain here.

Now the app is working on both Web and Android emulator (with firebase+Ionic 2 + Angularjs)

Thanks anyway :-)